# Map an external IP address to a VM

Tags: networking, virtual, vps, box, dedicated

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask this however I'm not really sure where else to go.

I'm currently working in the web hosting industry and providing support for cPanel, VPS servers, domains SSLs, Server Management, DNS and more and I'm not really sure how IP Addresses are mapped to virtual machines.

As an example scenario, if I have a VPS from any provide which has 4 Dedicated IP Addresses assigned by the provider.

Is it possible to somehow assign those IP's as the Public IP for any VMs provisioned running under VirtualBox on that VPS?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do something like this
[Configure an IP address on a virtual machine](http://www.ovh.com/us/g582.configure_an_ip_address_on_a_virtual_machine)
 and you can build something more enhanced like `gns3` or `vyatta` to do your own virtual lab with `routers` or `switches` or `firewall` or `ips/ids` with real IOS check gns3 tutorials from keith [gns3 tutorials](http://www.cbtnuggets.com/it-training/gns3-training)